# Problems with adjusting display brightness in Ubuntu 21.04 Samsung Galaxy Book Pro 360 13.3"

Tags: xorg, brightness, samsung

Got a new laptop (Samsung Galaxy Book Pro 360) and i'm having issues with the display brightness not working. I've tried using software to control it as well as using the brightness control on the keyboard and nothing seems to work.

i tried adding
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
to my grub file and updating grub then rebooting, did not work.

also tried doing that and creating a `80-backlight.conf` file and putting it in `usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` and still nothing.

i have also noticed that inside of the `usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` there are files named `10-amdgpu.conf` and `10-radeon.conf` which is strange considering this is an intel laptop and should be using intel intergrated graphics not anything amd.

also, just to point out, screen dimming works in the case of the laptop being idle for a certain amount of time, just cannot be controlled manually via software or keyboard controls.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. My laptop is Samsung Galaxy Book2 pro. I added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"` to my grub file, however it didn't work.

Thus, I tried the method introduced in  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Backlight#OLED_screen_brightness.

What I have done is  writing a new file named `backlight.rules` in the folder `/etc/udev/rules.d`, and the file contains the following udev rule:

```
RUN+="/bin/chgrp video /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
RUN+="/bin/chmod g+w /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
```

Then, the brightness control in upper left of the desktop works.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/F-i-f/soft-brightness seems to be the only solution that works for (AM)OLED screens running on Wayland with Intel processor.

After installing soft-brightness, brightness gets adjusted via both Ubuntu control and keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

if anyone stumbles upon this thread;

i fixed the issue by updating kernel version to 5.14. i was previously using version 5.10 or 5.11. Editing the grub file might also be needed, not sure as i had already edited the file and i do not know if the file is overwritten/replaced when updated to a newer kernel version.