# "Artificially" darkening screen on Ubuntu?

Tags: brightness

For some reason, my laptop (Samsung galaxy book 12) refuses to let me change the screen's brightness. I've tried about every option I've seen online (changes in .conf files, new dev rules, xrandr/brightness controller, etc) but nothing works and I guess there isn't much more I can do about it.

Unfortunately that doesn't stop the screen from burning my eyes and giving me headaches, even with Ubuntu's night mode turned on...
My question is, does anyone know if there's a way to artificially darken my screen? Some kind of dark filter I could apply so it makes it a bit more bearable?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What *exactly* did you try? Did you check the support and documentation for your laptop? Backlight brightness is often controlled by the hardware itself and not the OS.

Comment: I have tried the methods listed [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360289/problems-with-adjusting-display-brightness-in-ubuntu-21-04-samsung-galaxy-book-p). They're the most common fixes I've found online, but I'm not good with hardware, so it might have not been very relevant?

Comment: the solutions you found won't work for Wayland, which is default on Ubuntu 22.04. If you switch to xorg then the xrandr solutions (and possibly some other ones) will work for you

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286458/does-wayland-have-an-equivalent-of-xrandr-for-changing-brightness-and-color-temp for solutions that don't involve switching to xorg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot change brightness (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Unity)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762764/cannot-change-brightness-ubuntu-16-04-lts-unity)

Comment: See whether the command line utility "light" (sudo apt install light) works for changing the screen brightness.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I've looked around a bit and tried installing some of those (light, gammastep, brightnessctl, brightness controller, etc), but they didn't do anything (the brightness value remained the same). I've made sure the brightness buttons work, but they seem to do the work as they should. Is it safe to assume it's some kind of driver issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update in case anyone ends up in the same situation as me.

I've been able to fix the issue thanks to [icc-brightness](https://github.com/udifuchs/icc-brightness). I can select a brightness level with my keyboard's brightness keys, and make the change effective on the screen with ./icc-brightness apply. I'm assuming the OLED screen was the real issue all along.